# How should I get a failed assert to return a non-zero exit code?

Tags: php-5.6

I just found out the expensive way (i.e. fail in production) that

```
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL, true);
assert(false);
```

terminates execution WITHOUT issuing a non-zero exit code. Where the sense is in that, goodness only knows.

How should I remedy this? EDIT: Without otherwise affecting the output e.g. via ASSERT_CALLBACK's suppression of the warning.

set_error_handler relying on Assert() issuing a Warning? Some option I haven't found?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a callback with exit code

```
<?php
        function assert_failure()
        {
                exit(-1);
        }
        assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,     true);
        assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'assert_failure');
        assert(false);     
?>
```

It will output:

```
$ php assert.php
$ echo $?
255
```

Also you can throw an exception: `throw new Exception('Assert failed');` instead of exit.

To still show the warning:

```
<?php
        if(assert(false) == false) exit(-1);     
?>
```

It will output:

```
$ php assert.php
Warning: assert(): assert(false) failed in /home/user/assert.php on line 9
$ echo $?
255
```

Comment: Thanks, but that also suppresses the warning. Without: http://i.imgur.com/aclJyXf.png With: http://i.imgur.com/H5LLeR2.png . I've updated my question to clarify that the exit code is the only think I want to change.

Comment: assert returns a boolean, `if(assert(false) == false) exit(-1);` will do the warning and return 255, don't forget to remove the assert_bail.

Comment: You're suggesting set the exit code by manually adding an exit() to every call of assert?

Comment: It's not a solution for you? You can change php.ini and throw an exception by default instead of warning `assert.exception = On`

Comment: "You can change php.ini and throw an exception by default instead of warning assert.exception = On" Thanks, but doesn't work here: http://i.imgur.com/wxG9DR7.png , http://i.imgur.com/d1SQCNw.png .

Comment: It's only to php7, php5 requires to do the callback to a function and then throw exception.